# "TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'" on matplotlib scatterplot function

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Getting an error while going through a course. The instructor's code works, but mine does not. Our code is the exact same - theirs is likely out of date. Been searching for a bit but can't find a good solution based on my code:

```
x_axis = DataFrame(df, columns=["production_budget_usd"])
y_axis = DataFrame(df, columns=["worldwide_gross_usd"])
plt.scatter(x_axis, y_axis)
plt.show()
```

This gives back the error;

"TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'"

Any help much appreciated.

Edit;

Screenshot of the full code since it will be much more helpful;

[image: Full code]

Comment: This message appears when you try to use a data type that is not hashable. The value being passed is probably a string instead of an integer. You need to convert it into a number data type. It would be helpful if you provide a snippet of the data, so people can reproduce it and try to help you.

Comment: Could you add the output of `df.describe()` to your post?

Comment: @RobinSage Added the full code to help

Comment: @JohanC should be on there now, added a screenshot

Comment: Please add the code itself rather than a screenshot, so people can copy it and reproduce it.

Comment: Your data seems to be text instead of numeric?  Also, you shouldn't convert again to a dataframe. Maybe `x_axis = df["production_budget_usd"].to_numpy()`?